# Math function to remove minus

Tags: c#, math, numbers, double

If input value is `-0.088` and I want take from `x = 0.8` like this `0.8 - -0.088` but in result I want get `0.712` instead of `0.888` as it would be with minus `0.8 - 0.088`.

How to remove minus from number without direct string processing, can I use some Math function for such case:

```
    double x1 = 0.8;
    double x2 = 0.8;
    double a = -0.088;
    double b = 0.088;

    x1 = (x1 - a); 
    x2 = (x2 - b); 

    Console.WriteLine("0.8 minus -0.088 equals to [ " + x1 + 
                 " ]\r\n0.8 minus 0.088 equals to [ " + x2 + " ]");
```

result:

```
 0.8 minus -0.088 equals to [ 0.888 ]
 0.8 minus 0.088 equals to [ 0.712 ]
```

desired result:

```
0.8 minus -0.088 equals to [ 0.712 ]
0.8 minus 0.088 equals to [ 0.712 ]
```

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk This is a `c#` question and not `c/c++`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing minus corresponds to the mathematical concept of [*absolute value*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value). .NET implementation of this function is [`Math.Abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method:

```
x1 = (x1 - Math.Abs(a));
```

Answer (score 4):

It is mathematically correct, though. Doing `0.8 - -0.088`, will result to `0.8 + 0.088`. Try using `Math.Abs` before subtracting them. Refer to this: https://www.dotnetperls.com/math-abs

```
  x1 = (x1 - Math.Abs(a)); 
  x2 = (x2 - Math.Abs(b));
```

This should return your desired result.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try to remember some MATHS from junior school and if you know you have a minus figure just multiply it by -1 to turn it positive or if you have a positive no multiply it by -1 to get a negative number.

In this example after we have converted the -8 into a positive 8 with *-1 the 2nd sum (z = y - x) actually adds the numbers together due to the double minus symbols next to each other and returns 18 as a - -b reverses the action to make a + b. LOL I can't believe I can remember simple algebra but not ABS!!

```
int x = -8;
int y = 10;
int z = y - (x *-1); 
Console.WriteLine(z); // z = 10 - 8 = 2
z = y - x; 
Console.WriteLine(z); // z = 10 - -8 = 18
```

Then again I use it all the time in my betting math my BOT uses so that's maybe why I remembered it!

Obviously ABS is simpler but as I was doing just this sum when I came across the page I thought I would waste time writing an answer.